# Google AppEngine automated shutdown script execution

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

All of a sudden google app engine started running shutdown script..there are no errors reports anywhere.. has anyone experienced this behavior?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The weekly restart maybe? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-instances-are-managed#restarts

Comment: Or, if configured for automatic scaling, instance shutdown due to reduction in traffic load?

Answer (score 0):

Machines in flex can get shut down for a few reasons:

- The instance went unhealthy, stopped responding to traffic
- Traffic slowed down, so the instance got auto-scaled down for you
- It was time for a weekly reboot so we could pick up security patches

We're rolling out a change in the next few days that makes figuring this stuff out much easier :D